# In power point how can I populate pasteboard with a path to a folder

Tags: vba, powerpoint, clipboard

I need to save a file to a specific folder. I have to click through a path. too many clicks

I want to create a button in power point slide. Clicking this button would copy the folder path on the clipboard. The the next button on the slide opens a word file and I press save as and paste the path to east my navigational nightmare.

I have created a power point slide.

Placed a few images and made them clickable.

Each click opens a certain file or folder.

Now I want a file X to be copied to a specific folder. Clicking a button opens the file X but to save a copy of the same to a specific folder I have to navigate again.

any solution?

Comment: Maybe you can do this with  VB but not sure if its just a built in feature of Powerpoint.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have so far (as text) so that we can assist further (the code relating to 'clicking a button opens the file X' and any other relevant code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't mind having to include the macro in every presentation, or saving it in another file that you open whenever you want to use it on the current active presentation:

```
Sub CopyPath()
    Dim oShp As Shape
    
    If Len(ActivePresentation.Path) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please save your presentation, then try again"
    Else
        Set oShp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontalRotatedFarEast, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.Path & "\"
        oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
        oShp.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Or to use a fixed path, per your comment below:

```
Sub CopyPath()
    Dim oShp As Shape
    Dim sPath as String

    ' EDIT THIS to be whatever path you like
    sPath = "C:\Temp\MyStuff\Goes\Here\"

    If Len(ActivePresentation.Path) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please save your presentation, then try again"
    Else
        Set oShp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontalRotatedFarEast, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sPath
        oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
        oShp.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

You'd need to save this in a PPTM rather than PPTX file. As long as the file's open you can use ALT+F8 to access it.

Comment: Mmm... This might be exactly what I need. will give it a try ... You guys rock!

Comment: Hi Steve Thank you. However I need to rework my question. I am using ppt as a webpage to open different folders or files. PPT itself will remain the same just like webpage. I just want a fixed predefined path to a folder on my drive to be copied to my pasteboard. Only so that I can quickly paste it when I am saving a copy of an open word file to that folder. This path to that folder remains fixed

Comment: for example D:\Dept\CONTROL Room\Stats\Overnight Parking\
I want this path copied (just as if I have pressed Ctrl+C) so a click on a photo in my power point page should serve as Ctrl+C and the path I desire is (above mentioned) when I press Ctrl+V in. Path will remain the same. It is not any variable. Hope it explains my question.

Comment: @IftikharAli I've edited my answer to add another version that will do what you're after.

Comment: impressive! let me try!

Comment: @IftikharAli  Aw, I'm just this guy, you know?  But glad to hear it works for you. Thanks!